# How to convert any Date time to UTC using ZonedDateTime or Java 8

Tags: java, date, java-8, zoneddatetime

I am trying to convert date `06-12-2015 02:10:10 PM` from default zone to UTC using `ZonedDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime utc = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

but `utc` returns `2015-12-06T14:10:10Z` instead of `06-12-2015 09:10:10 AM`

How can I convert date from default zone to UTC? The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142864/how-to-get-utc0-date-in-java8) convert current time to UTC.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant, ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) where the second parameter is `UTC` (the instant knows the local offset). Something like,

```
String source = "06-12-2015 02:10:10 PM";
String pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(source);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I get (corresponding to my local zone offset)

```
06-12-2015 06:10:10 PM
```

Comment: if I do this `Date date1 = Date.from(zdt.toInstant())`  it returns original time `06-12-2015 02:10:10 PM` why?

Comment: Why mix SimpleDateFormat in with java.time code? Why not let java.time do the parsing?

Comment: @BasilBourque OP's code included `date.toInstant()`, I assumed that was the question.

Answer (score 4):

#### 06-12-2015 02:10:10 PM in Pakistan = 06-12-2015 09:10:10 AM in UTC

There are many ways to do it.

1. Parse to `LocalDateTime` ➡️ Combine it with your timezone to get `ZonedDateTime` ➡️ Convert to `Instant` ➡️ Convert to `ZonedDateTime` using [`Instant#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) and UTC timezone.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "06-12-2015 02:10:10 PM";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);

        // Using ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi") for the demo. Change it to
        // ZoneId.systemDefault()
        Instant instant = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi")).toInstant();

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        System.out.println(zdtUtc.format(dtf)); // 06-12-2015 09:10:10 AM
    }
}
```

2. Parse to `LocalDateTime` ➡️ Combine it with your timezone to get `ZonedDateTime` ➡️ Convert to `Instant` ➡️ Convert to `ZonedDateTime` using [`ZonedDateTime#ofInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) and UTC timezone.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "06-12-2015 02:10:10 PM";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);

        // Using ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi") for the demo. Change it to
        // ZoneId.systemDefault()
        Instant instant = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi")).toInstant();

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        System.out.println(zdtUtc.format(dtf)); // 06-12-2015 09:10:10 AM
    }
}
```

3. **Using [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-):**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "06-12-2015 02:10:10 PM";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);

        // Using ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi") for the demo. Change it to
        // ZoneId.systemDefault()
        ZonedDateTime zdtPak = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi"));

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = zdtPak.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        System.out.println(zdtUtc.format(dtf)); // 06-12-2015 09:10:10 AM
    }
}
```

4. **Using [`DateTimeFormatter#withZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-java.time.ZoneId-) and [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-):**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "06-12-2015 02:10:10 PM";

        // Using ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi") for the demo. Change it to
        // ZoneId.systemDefault()
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M-d-u h:m:s a", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                        .withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi"));

        ZonedDateTime zdtPak = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfInput);

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = zdtPak.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(zdtUtc.format(dtfOutput)); // 06-12-2015 09:10:10 AM
    }
}
```

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Excellent well researched answer with lot of sample code