# How to get Date in UTC+0 in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, java-time

I am using the following code to get the date in ISO-8601 format. For UTC the value returned does not contain offset.

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(
                                       Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochInMilliSec), zoneId);

return dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

For other time formats the response returned looks like:

> 2016-10-30T17:00:00-07:00

In case of UTC the value returned is:

> 2016-10-30T17:00:00Z

I want it to be:

> 2016-10-30T17:00:00+00:00

Note: Do not use UTC-0 as -00:00 is not ISO8601 compliant.

Comment: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in formatter uses `Z` when the offset is zero. The `Z` is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

You'll have to use a custom formatter, using a [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) to set a custom text for when the offset is zero:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date and time, use built-in
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    // append offset, set "-00:00" when offset is zero
    .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "-00:00")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();

System.out.println(dateTime.format(fmt));
```

This will print:

> 2016-10-30T17:00:00-00:00

---

Just reminding that `-00:00` is not [ISO8601 compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators). The standard allows only  `Z` and `+00:00` (and the variations `+0000` and `+00`) when the offset is zero.

If you want `+00:00`, just change the code above to:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date and time, use built-in
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    // append offset
    .appendPattern("xxx")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
```

This formatter will produce the output:

> 2016-10-30T17:00:00+00:00

Comment: Wouldn't it append -00:00 in all cases?

Comment: My bad..It won't

Comment: @PriyaJain It'll append `-00:00` only if the offset is zero. For all other offsets, it will follow the format `+HH:MM` (signal + or - followed by hour:minute)

Comment: @Hugo or simply use `xxx` for the time zone.

Comment: @assylias `xxx` will print `+00:00`, but the OP wants `-00:00`

Comment: @Hugo Oh, I didn't see the `-`, fair enough.

Comment: @PriyaJain Just reminding that `-00:00` is not ISO8601 compliant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators - when the offset is zero, the standard allows only `Z` or `+00:00`

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have changed it to be +00:00 instead.

Comment: @PriyaJain Please edit your Question’s body and title if you are willing to use + instead of -. And maybe add a note about avoiding minus.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept `+00:00` instead of `-00:00`, you can also use a simpler `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx");

OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-10-30T17:00:00Z");
System.out.println(fmt.format(odt));
```

I used `x` whereas the standard `toString()` method of `OffsetDateTime` uses `X`. The main difference between `x` and `X` is that one return `+00:00` vs. `Z` for the other.