# How get the UTC date in ms?

Tags: java, android

I would like the current date in ms.

I am with the *API23*, I can't use `Instant.now()`.

```
tvDateUTC.setText(Instant.now().toString());
```

I would like to retrieve something that looks like this:

```
1549536499906
```

Comment: Check the doc: [Instant#toEpochMilli](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli())

Comment: Looks like duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142864/how-to-get-utc0-date-in-java-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()
```

The java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() method returns the current time in milliseconds.The unit of time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger.

For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved:

```
private String getDate(){
    String ts = String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    return ts;
}
```

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

Using .getTime() method will return date in milliseconds.

eg.

```
Date currentDate = new Date();

System.out.println(currentDate.getTime());
```

Alternatively you can use

```
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.bp.Instant  // Represent a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds using this back-port to early Java.  
.now()                   // Capture the current moment in UTC. 
.toEpochMilli()          // Determine the count of milliseconds from the first moment of 1970 in UTC to this recorded moment.
```

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time types are terrible. So you should definitely be using their replacement, the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later, and in Android 26 and later.

Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

Further adapted to early Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.